# Setup Cassandra for Django - "AttributeError: 'SystemManager' object has no attribute 'describe_keyspace'"

Tags: django, cassandra, thrift, pycassa

I've followed step-by-step guide in https://github.com/thobbs/twissandra

I'm stuck at `python manage.py sync_cassandra` where I got message:

```
['/home/z/twissandra', '/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg', '/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-0.8.2-py2.6.egg', '/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6', '/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pycassa-1.0.5-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenv-1.5.1-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/z/twiss/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/home/z/twissandra/tweets/management/commands/sync_cassandra.py", line 17, in handle_noargs
    sys.describe_keyspace('Twissandra')
AttributeError: 'SystemManager' object has no attribute 'describe_keyspace'
```

I have no idea about this. What to do?

Comment: what cassandra version are you running against?

Comment: Cassandra version: 0.7.1-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just noticed that I never merged the sync_cassandra branch (which fixes this issue) into my master branch, because I was expecting ericflo to accept the pull request a little more quickly.

I just merged a moment ago, so pull the master branch and try again.  By the way, github is probably a more appropriate place for this question than SO.

Answer (score 0):

Little tip, If you’re getting this error in Python and you have no idea why, check for circular imports. That’s what the problem was for me.

A circular import is for example module A imports module B and module B imports module A. There are certain scenarios where this doesn’t work.